# Android calendar custom event color keeps changing to default (blue)

Tags: android, events, calendar, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am developing an android app that programmatically adds some events to the user's default calendar using a ContentResolver.

I also set the color of the events based on the type of the event (in my case: green for holidays, red for workdays). This works fine but after a few minutes all the custom coloring turns to blue (default google calendar event color). I use a Nexus 5X for debugging. Any idea how to solve this?

Screenshots:
**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Code:

```
// add work day event
if (DateFrom > today.getTimeInMillis() && WorkType == '0') {
                ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, DateFrom);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, DateTo);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, Team + " (Id: " + Id + ")");
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Work Day.");
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, DEFAULT_CALENDAR_ID);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().toString());
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, Color.RED);

                Uri eventUri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
                long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
}

// add day off event
if (DateFrom > today.getTimeInMillis() && WorkType == '2' && IsApproved != null && IsApproved.equals("true")) {

                ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, 1);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, DateFrom + 3600000);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "P23H");
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Day Off!" + " (Id: " + Id + ")");
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Day Off");
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, Color.GREEN);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, DEFAULT_CALENDAR_ID);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, false);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().toString());

                Uri eventUri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
                long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:

> EVENT_COLOR
>
> A secondary color for the individual event. This should only be updated by the  **sync adapter** for a given account.

**UPD:**
The right way is to use `EVENT_COLOR_KEY` that you can select from `CalendarContract.Colors`. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#EVENT_COLOR_KEY)